# Nesting resources in EmberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am pretty new to EmberJS framework and I wonder how could I make something working like this:

- on index page is a list of universities,
- after clicking on a particular university a list of majors from that university shows,
- after clicking on a particular major a list of subjects shows.

What I did in JavaScript is something like this:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('index', { path: '/' }, function(){
    this.resource('universities', { path: 'univs'}, function(){
      this.resource('university', { path: '/:universities_id'}, function(){
        this.resource('majors', { path: 'majors'}, function(){
          this.resource('major', { path: '/:majors_id'}, function(){
            this.resource('subjects', { path: 'subjects'}, function(){
            });//subjects
          });//major
        });//majors
      });//university
    });//universities       
  });//index
  this.resource('about');
  this.resource('contact');
});
```

Could you tell me if this is a correct way to do it and if it is, could you tell me how can I write the templates necessary to pull it off?

Comment: The router map is basically the blueprint/structure of your app, by asking how to implement this writing templates you are basically asking to write your entire app for you, so why don't you start writing your code and ask a particular question where you did get stuck?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is correct way. but you don't need resource 'index'.

You can put templates in html page and render them in router (use renderTemplate).

http://jsbin.com/abiLaPi/1 - reduced version.

http://jsbin.com/abiLaPi/1/edit - source code.

Comment: Could you tell me one more thing: how can I have those lists side by side? Now one list replaces another.

Comment: Now I've made it in a little different way. However I don't know why it doesn't work. My source code: http://jsbin.com/AQAref/1/ It doesn't render the 'university' template correctly. It is really weird because after clicking on university it doesn't work but when i refresh the page it renders correctly.